# Confused about the jQuery $.each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, each

Let's say I have

```
$.each(data,function(i,item){
                ...
            });
```

I get that $.each is going to iterate over the object (or array) data but I am confused about the function. Why is "i" incrementing by 1 ("i"++) over the loop and what defines "item" to be data[i]? Is this just a built in function mechanic applied to every item in the object or array?

Thanks

Comment: This is all pretty clear in the jQuery docs. You should read them. The way `$.each` is defined is what determines the parameters for the callback.

Comment: Think of it this way: You are passing a callable function as an argument to `$.each`; that function can therefore be called from within `$.each` using whatever arguments it feels like using. It just so happens that jQuery guarantees it will always be called with the loop counter (zero-based) as its first argument and the array item value as its second argument. You can see it in action by looking at the jQuery source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's .each() function calls your callback function with element's index as first parameter and element's value as second parameter.
You can find relevant documentation here:
http://devdocs.io/jquery/jquery.each

Comment: First parameter is a KEY and second is a VALUE. For an array KEY would be INDEX (as e-neko described) but for the object key would be VARIABLE-NAME.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly a built in jquery function, for each item (looped with a for it applies the function that you provided, passing to the function index and element[index]). Also it's smarter than that it detects if the first argument in $.each is a json or array - for array - the index is passed for json the key is passed along with the values).

A similar implementation would look like this:

```
function each(x, fn) {
   if(x.constructor == Array) {
     for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        fn(i, x[i]);
     }
   } else if (x.constructor == Object) {
     for(var key in x) {
         fn(key, x[key]);
     }
   } else {
     throw Exception('Non array or object passed');
   }
}
each([1,2,3], function(ind, el) {console.log(ind, el)});
each({x:1, y:2}, function (key, el) { console.log(key, el) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "hypothetical implementation" that shows how this can be achieved:

```
var myEachFunction = function (array, callback) {
    var i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; ++i) {
        callback(i, array[i]);
    }
};

// Usage: myEachFunction([5, 6, 7], function (i, item) {
//     doSomething();
// });
```

In this implementation, I am calling the provided callback function with the loop index and the item value, in that order.

jQuery's implementation is similar, but much more sophisticated. Besides things like error/argument checking, it also supports iterating over objects, not just arrays. The jQuery documentation provides more information on what arguments are passed in what order.